# Объясните смысл индекса по битовой карте в Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Помогите разобраться, как устроено индексное сканирование по битовой карте в постгрес? Нашёл вот такое определение

> Основная идея индекса на основе битовых карт (bitmap-индекса) состоит в том, что одна и та же битовая карта (последовательность бит) может указывать на диапазон строк, у которых значение bitmap-индекса соответствует значению данной битовой карты. Таким образом, чем больше одна и та же битовая карта содержит указателей на значащие строки и эти указатели максимально компактно упорядочены, тем меньше размер битового индекса и, соответственно, использование данного индекса является более эффективным при доступе к данным с низкой селективностью. То есть битовый индекс не избирателен в отличие от индекса на основе В-дерева.

собственно, может кто-нибудь объяснить этот тип «на пальцах»?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более привычный `index scan` выдаёт следующий `TID` (`Tuple Identifier`) по одному строго по очереди. Получив из `index scan` очередной `TID` - идём проверять видимость транзакции для этой строки, доставать остальные поля и проверять остальные условия запроса, если есть. Если строка подходит по условиям - то возвращаем её на вышестоящий узел плана выполнения (или запросившей эти данные программе если выше никого нет). Затем берём из индекса следующий `TID`.

`bitmap index scan` сначала получает все подходящие под условие индексного поиска `TID` из индекса, затем по порядку запрашивает соответствующие блоки самой таблицы. Порядок чтения физически таблицы так получается более предсказуемый, для `bitmap index scan` можем использовать вызовы posix fadvise для информирования операционной системы, что нам скоро понадобятся вот такие вот блоки (это всё на что действительно влияет настройка `effective_io_concurrency`), readahead вероятно тоже будет чуть более полезен чем обычно. Промежуточная структура данных, используемая для хранения `TID` или целых страниц таблицы, которые нужно прочесть из таблицы и называется bitmap.

Что интересно, `bitmap index scan` может быть `lossy`. У индекса есть возможность вернуть строки, которые *возможно* подходят под условие поиска, но это нужно проверить после чтения действительных данных блока. Например, индексный метод `brin` может сказать "на этой странице данных в таблице есть подходящие записи", но не сказать какие именно, он не хранит сами `TID`, только номера страниц. При недостатке `work_mem` bitmap может сам перейти в режим `lossy`: отметить на битовой карте, что нужно прочитать все строки со страницы и отбросить лишнее - это существенно компактнее по памяти, чем отмечать на битовой карте конкретные строки.

Но при этом bitmap, конечно, вообще не способен возвращать данные в отсортированном виде. Типичный запрос показать "10 последних по дате чего бы то ни было" будет неэффективно выполнять через bitmap (вполне возможно, что seqscan будет даже удобнее), но элементарное действие для `index scan`.